# The "Xamarin.Build.Download.XamarinBuildCastAssemblyResources" task could not be loaded from the assembly [App center]

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-app-center

I have problem with building Xamarin.iOS project on AppCenter:

```
"/Users/runner/runners/2.166.4/work/1/s/fiba/fiba.iOS/fiba.iOS.csproj" (Rebuild target) (4) ->
(_XamarinBuildCastAssemblyResources target) -> 
  /Users/runner/.nuget/packages/xamarin.build.download/0.9.0/buildTransitive/Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(79,3): error MSB4062: The "Xamarin.Build.Download.XamarinBuildCastAssemblyResources" task could not be loaded from the assembly /Users/runner/.nuget/packages/xamarin.build.download/0.9.0/buildTransitive/Xamarin.Build.Download.dll.  Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [/Users/runner/runners/2.166.4/work/1/s/fiba/fiba.iOS/fiba.iOS.csproj]
```

SDK version is 13.14
XCode version is 11.4

Comment: You could update the version of SDK to 13.16 , which is support for Xcode 11.4 .

Comment: I tried, the same error :(

Comment: It would better to get support for App Center directly from within the App Center portal . Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/help .

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?